# Poisson processs

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process, poisson-process

Let $N=(N(t))_{t\geq 0}$ be a Poisson process with continuous intensity function $(\lambda(t))_{t\geq0} $.

a) Show that the intensities $\lambda_{n, n+k}(t)$, $n\geq0$, $k\geq1$ and $t>0$, of the Matov process $N$ with transition probabilities $p_{n,n+k}(s,t)$ exist, i.e., $$\lambda_{n, n+k}(t)=\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{p_{n,n+k}(t,t+h)}{h}, \text{   } n\geq0    \text{     }, k\geq1,$$ and that they are given by $$\lambda_{n,n+k}(t)= \begin{cases} \lambda(t), k=1 \\ 0, k\geq2\end{cases} .$$

b) What can you conclude from $p_{n,n+k}(t,t+h)$ for $h$ small about the short term jump behavior of the Markov process $N$?

c) Show by counterexample that system from a) in is general not valid if one gives up the assumption of continuity of the intensity function $\lambda(t)$.

So I started to learn about Poisson process by myself. But this looks really hard to me... didn't find any examples how should I solve exercises like this one. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I am assuming "Matov" should be "Markov"? And by "continuous intensity function $\lambda(t)$ you mean that it is a time-inhomogeneous Poisson process, correct?

Comment: @Math1000 yes! You are right

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "time-inhomogeneous Poisson process," in that case?